# How to use 'contains' with manytomany field?

Tags: django-models, many-to-many, lookup, django-related-manager

I have a model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, null = True, blank = True)
```

I have to execute  a query

`tasks_for_myuser = Tasks.objects.filter(assigend_to__contains = myuser)`

But this is throwing an error. 
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains`

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to filter Tasks which has `assigned_to` field set to `myuser`, you can simply query like this.
`tasks_for_myuser = Tasks.objects.filter(assigend_to = myuser)`
You don't really require `contains` here, since it is a many-to-many field.